# How to set focus to button in react and material ui on Dialog properly?

Tags: reactjs, button, material-ui, dialog, focus

When I used code :

```
                <DialogActions>
                    <Button onClick={handleClose}>Disagree</Button>
                    <Button onClick={handleClose} autoFocus>
                        Agree
                    </Button>
                </DialogActions>
```

it give me the error:

Line 35:51:  The autoFocus prop should not be used, as it can reduce usability and accessibility for users  jsx-a11y/no-autofocus

So I used different approach:

```
import { useState, useRef, useEffect } from 'react';
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';
import Dialog from '@mui/material/Dialog';
import DialogActions from '@mui/material/DialogActions';
import DialogContent from '@mui/material/DialogContent';
import DialogContentText from '@mui/material/DialogContentText';
import DialogTitle from '@mui/material/DialogTitle';

import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

export default function DialogYesNo(props) {
    const { parentShowAlert, parentOnCloseDialog, dialogTitle, dialogText } = props;

    const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        setOpen(parentShowAlert);
    }, [parentShowAlert]);

    const handleClose = () => {
        setOpen(false);
        parentOnCloseDialog();
    };

    const cancelButtonRef = useRef(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (open && cancelButtonRef.current) {
            cancelButtonRef.current.focus();
        }
    }, [open]);

    return (
        <div>
            <Dialog open={open} onClose={handleClose} aria-labelledby="alert-dialog-title" aria-describedby="alert-dialog-description">
                <DialogTitle id="alert-dialog-title">{dialogTitle}</DialogTitle>
                <DialogContent>
                    <DialogContentText id="alert-dialog-description">{dialogText}</DialogContentText>
                </DialogContent>
                <DialogActions>
                    <Button onClick={handleClose} ref={cancelButtonRef}>
                        No
                    </Button>
                    <Button onClick={handleClose}>Agree</Button>
                </DialogActions>
            </Dialog>
        </div>
    );
}

DialogYesNo.propTypes = {
    parentShowAlert: PropTypes.bool,
    parentOnCloseDialog: PropTypes.func,
    dialogTitle: PropTypes.string,
    dialogText: PropTypes.string
};
```

But code cancelButtonRef.current.focus() is never fired, because cancelButtonRef is always null and button  is not set as focused.

Do you know what is wrong in my code?

Comment: what version of **material-ui** you are using ? autofocus in button  is working fine in **mui5**

Comment: I am using matarial-ui version 5.8.6

Answer (score 0):

This question is a couple of months old, but maybe my answer can help someone anyway...

I had a similar issue, but I was using a primereact dialog. I used the dialog 'onShow' callback. Not using JSX, the code below did it for me:

```
createElement(primereact.Dialog, {onShow:() => focusRef.current.focus(), ...
```

I assume that material-ui dialog has something similar.